# php - save file from webserver into Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my program I try to create a website where the user can upload and download files. I created the page and the user is able to upload a file to the webserver. Now I don't know how I can make it possible to let the user download his file again. Do I need to save it into a database?

index.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="post">

Select File: <br>

<input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="80"> <br>
<input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload File">

</form>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
    $file_result ="";

    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        $file_result .= "No File Uploaded";
        $file_result .= "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } 
    else {
        $file_result .=
        "Upload: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] . "<br>" .
        "Type: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["type"] . "<br>" .
        "Size: " . ($_FILES ["file"] ["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br>" .
        "Tempfile: " . $_FILES ["file"] ["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"xxx/uploads/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $file_result .= "File Upload sucessful";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with uploading the file to a directory; what you'll probably want to do is then save the (string) filepath to your database. This will be much faster than actually storing the file in the DB. Make sure the file directory is only readable/writable by the web server process.

Comment: Ah okay, I see! So I will store the path into the database and probably the name I guess. How can I add it to the database? I create a database with a table consisting of 2 columns, how do I add it there and how can I invoke it from the database to the downloadpage?

Comment: You'll want to use PDO to access your database from PHP. This sounds like multiple other questions, though. I'd recommend looking at other resolved questions here

Comment: Okay, I try to figure it out as far as I can. Thank you so far!